# Check for set of characters in a string

Tags: c#, string

Given a string, how can you check if a set of characters exist (and find their location) inside the string such that the characters need to be in the same order but not consecutive.

for example the string "INEEDTOGETAHAIRCUT" and the set to find {'O','E','G','T'}

Thanks

(ps - i have already tried a brute force attempt but it is terrible and doesn't work!)

Comment: Question not clear. "So long as the follow each other, they can be in any order." That seems to be self-contradictory.

Comment: well the charachters cannot appear anywhere in the string, the must be sequential, but the ordering doesn't matter - hmmm i can see why that might sound unclear. I am not sure how else to explain

Comment: So you need to find 4 consecutive characters in the test string that exhausts the set `{'O','E','G','T'}`

Comment: Is a value of 'OOOO' allowed or do you want to search for any combination of O E G and T?

Comment: OOOO is not allowed and yes 4 consecutive charachters that satisfy the set OEGT

Comment: Im pretty sure whoever edited the question, changed the logic of it.  I don't think it was that unclear...

Comment: @Akron Hmm. The new question is completely different to Ricki's comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I'm not 100% sure of what you mean with "the characters follow each other", here is a possible approach: generate all the possible permutations of the characters sequence
and search for the permutation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program {

    static IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(string value) {
        if (value.Length == 1) {
            yield return value;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
                string a = value[i].ToString();
                foreach (string b in GetPermutations(value.Remove(i, 1))) {
                    yield return a + b;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string test = "INEEDTOGETAHAIRCUT";
        string chars = "OEGT";
        foreach (string to_find in GetPermutations(chars)) {
            int i = test.IndexOf(to_find);
            if (i != -1) {
                Console.WriteLine("Found {0} at index {1}", to_find, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, my only problem with this is the order of complexity.  But that probably doesn't matter for the asker.

Answer (score 1):

With System.Linq in your usings you can do this:

```
"INEEDTOGETAHAIRCUT".ToCharArray().Any(c => c=='O' || c=='E' || c=='G' || c=='T');
```

Or write a new extension method to accept a char array as the argument.
 To have any "sequence" of chars in any order you can do this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{

    public static bool ContainsAnySequenceOf(this String str, List<char> charArray)
    {
        foreach (char c in charArray)
        {
            if (str.ToCharArray().Any(x => x == c))
            {
                charArray.Remove(c);
                return str.Substring(str.IndexOf(c), Math.Min(str.Length - str.IndexOf(c), charArray.Count)).ContainsAnySequenceOf(charArray);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
"INEEDTOGETAHAIRCUT".ContainsAnySequenceOf(new List<char> {'O','E','G','T'});
```

Comment: ahhh that is perfect but unfortunately i need to no where rather than just true or false. I really should have mentioned this :/

Comment: Ok. I've better understand your question now and edited my answer to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something even more simple only to two lines to check what you need

```
string strCompare = "INEEDTOGETAHAIRCUT";
string strStringContains = ""AHRI"; 
var matchingString = strCompare.IndexOfAny(strStringContains.ToCharArray()) != -1;
then wrap the matchingString in an if(matchingString){ } // should return true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

You can use [String.IndexOfAny()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) to find the first character of the sequence.

Then iterate over the following characters in the string to check that each of them is included in the set of legal characters. For each character you find from your list (including the first one you found), remove it from the list of legal characters that can follow, to disallow duplicates.

If you hit an illegal character, the text isn't a match, so go back to the beginning of this algorithm to process the remaining part of the string.

If you find all the legal characters in a row, then you have your result.

Comment: that returns the index of the first occurance of any character from my set opposed to the first occurance where they all appear together if that makes sense?

Comment: But that doesn't meet the need "as the characters follow each other"

Comment: Sorry, the question was a little unclear. Updated my answer with a bit more help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very inelegant old school approach to solving the problem. Although I'm sure some of the code could be more efficient, it avoids enumerating all permutations of the search set (as is done in the answer you accepted). Doing that could get expensive.

```
static bool matchesPermutation(string test, string search)
{
    string remaining = search;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
    {
        int pos = remaining.IndexOf(test[i]);
        if (pos == -1)
            return false;
        else
            remaining = remaining.Remove(pos, 1);
    }
    return true;
}

static int findPermutation(string test, string search)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < test.Length-search.Length+1; i++)
        if (matchesPermutation(test.Substring(i, search.Length), search))
            return i;
    return -1;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = "INEEDTOGETAHAIRCUT";
    string search = "AHRI";
    int foundPos = findPermutation(test, search);
    Console.WriteLine(foundPos);
    if (foundPos != -1)
        Console.WriteLine(test.Substring(foundPos, search.Length));
}
```